# Why is my new Azure web service not installing nuget packages in the packages.config file?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to setup my first Azure Web Service using a GitHub repository. I've included the packages.config file in the repository and I can see it in the Web Service console.

```
D:\home\site\repository>type packages.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Faker.Net" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="YamlDotNet" version="8.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

When the Deployment Center logs shows errors indicating the Newtonsoft.Json package is not loaded.

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Site deployment.
d:\home\site\repository\App_Code\Sling.cs(1): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Admin.metaproj]
d:\home\site\repository\App_Code\Sling.cs(2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Admin.metaproj]
...
```

Using the console, I can look in the Bin directory and see the packages are not installed. Am I wrong in thinking the packages should be installed? What else can I do different so they will be installed?

Thanks,
Russ

Comment: You might want to re-tag your question, you tagged it with Amazon-Web-Services, might get more viewed from the right people if you tag it with Azure.

Comment: So right you are DC, thanks. I totally miss-filed that one.

Comment: Use this command in your project on Kudu: `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json --version 12.0.2`, test whether it can be installed.

Comment: BowmanZhu, thanks for the idea. I'm not familiar with Kudu, where would I test this command? In the Azure App Service Console, in the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory?

Comment: @RussPetersen Hey, remember @ other's name under your question next time, otherwise they can't receive your reply. I am sorry that I remember it  wrong. This command is not used like this.

Comment: @RussPetersen In addition to this error, are there other errors?

Comment: @RussPetersen No Prob, thought it would help get more views by the right people. :)